# Do parent containers wrap router outlets and other modules?

Tags: html, css, angular

weird problem. With this code:

```
<body style="border: solid 3px blue">
    <app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>
    <div [@routeAnimations]="getOutlet(outlet)">
        <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
    </div>
</body>
```

`<body>` only wraps `<nav-bar>`, evident by the blue border. From my understanding, it should wrap both `<nav-bar>` and `<router-outlet>`. Does this normally occur with router-outlets? Any help is appreciated. I am running angular 13.

Here is an image of the result. it is only about half of the page.

[img of the blue box outline only encapsulating  the area of the first module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrqWb.png)

Comment: do you have a fixed height for your `body`? try changing the height to `height: max-content;`

Comment: Tried! Still only wrapping <nav-module>.

Comment: Take a loot at your ```position``` attributes - maybe there is ```position:absolute```.
Or try setting your body to ```body {min-height: 100vh;}``` (body will fill at least the available viewport size)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. In all my component templates, I wrapped the content with a specific class. When I removed this class, the wrapping worked as intended. I'm not sure why it works exactly. My guess is that it was because it interfered with how angular handles classes and modules or it was the way the CSS class properties were interacting.